# Легенда (<legend>) о которой вспоминают редко!

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Здравствуйте дорогие друзья!

---

Вёрсткой веб-сайтов занимаюсь с 20.03.2019г. поэтому вопрос!
Необходимо было сверстать вот именно то, что вы видите в примере данного вопроса, кстати это сделал я! Вопрос в следующем, если вы прочитаете данный код, то не сложно заметить, насколько пришлось изощриться, чтобы добиться данного результата (именно перевёрнутой кнопки в блоке legend), там, как вы смеете заметить rotate(180deg) блока fildset, его внутренностей, и другие элементы "накуренности" в коде! В общем, если у кого-то есть другие идеи реализации этой кнопки (чтобы она была не на верху, как по умолчанию, а внизу фальцета) буду благодарен за ответ! И если на ум придут минусы технологии разработанной мной, озвучивайте не стесняйтесь, я учусь, поэтому держу свою самооценку на уровне соседа пьяницы!-_-

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  background-color: #282828;
}

.main-body-wrapper{
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content__slider{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 62px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.content__slider-inner{
  width: 538px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: transparent;
  border: none;
}


.content__slider-inner h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-family: "Sansation-Bold";
  font-size: 48px;
}

.content__slider-inner p{
  font-family: "Sansation-Regular";
  font-size: 10.3px;
  margin-top: 34px;
}

.content__slider-buttom{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 11px 33px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Sansation-Regular";
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.content__slider-buttom:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #097e89;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.content__slider-inner h1, .content__slider-inner p, .content__slider-buttom{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.content__slider-inner{
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
 <div class="content__slider">
                  <fieldset class="content__slider-inner">
                    <legend class="gosu-item"><div class="content__slider-buttom">hire us</div></legend>
                      <p>We provide the best services in the world We privede the best services in the World<br>We privede the best services in the World</p>
                    <h1>the best service</h1><br>
                  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Ух, как я не люблю, когда в интерфейсе что-то двигается, скачет, выползает, меняется... даже кушать не могу от злости. | Наводим курсор мышки на левую границу блока HIRE US - и понеслась! (you're fired)

Comment: Alexander Petrov эмм, по больше конструктива пожалуйста, я не понимаю твоей агрессии, либо у тебя ie3 и как-то не так это всё отображается, либо я не понимаю сути твоей претензии? Кстати, для тебя специально могу прописать, чтобы f-size в кнопке менялся на :hover ! ;D

Comment: Это не агрессия. Я действительно не люблю переусложненные интерфейсы с ездящими элементами. И на часто посещаемых сайтах нещадно вырезаю финтифлюшки с помощью адблока и т. п. | Наведи мышку на левую кромку кнопки - она начинает дергаться. Firefox.

Comment: Alexandr Petrov , у меня ничего не дёргается гоголь хром ... Ну чтож, как говорится на вкус и цвет... Удачи вам !

Comment: Проверил в Chrome. Поведение совсем другое. PS: таки fired. Веб-дизигнер _обязан_ сделать так, чтобы работало во всех браузерах.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, согласен, но ещё тут обычно отвечают на конкретные вопросы, а не цепляются к совсем не существенным в контексте данного обсуждения вещам ! -_- Шах и мат

Comment: Я ж не написал это в ответе. А комментарии как раз предназначены для уточнения деталей (детали уточнены: в хроме работает, в лисе - нет).

Comment: Alexander Petrov  =\

Comment: красиво сделано. поставил плюс

Comment: Красиво. Но я бы сделал просто блоками с позиционированием - более кросс-браузерно и менее геморройно.